# Meaning of "range is down to intrinsic differences between the vaccines"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> their efficacy against all symptomatic cases of the disease found in trials has been lower, ranging between 66% and 95%. **Some of that range is down to intrinsic differences between the vaccines**.

Source: [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/briefing/2021/02/13/when-covid-19-vaccines-meet-the-new-variants-of-the-virus)

What does the bold text mean?

It clearly makes no sense if I understand "intrinsic differences between the vaccines" as the number of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Down to" in this sentence is used to mean "a result of". See [definition 12 of "down" here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/down), where it's marked as chiefly British usage.

So the sentence means:

> Some of the variance between 66% and 95% is caused by differences in the vaccines themselves.